# создать запрос в MS SQL Managment studio

Tags: sql, view

нужно создать представление, в котором посчитать число студентов на  каждой специальности, отсортировав по числу студентов в порядке убывания. вот код моего друга и он не работает(функции substring необходимо 3 аргумента):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(Code_Spec, 0, CHARINDEX(‘-’,Group_number),1) AS Spec, COUNT(*) AS COUNTGROUP
FROM     dbo.Students_Info
GROUP BY Code_Spec
```

вот код под мою базу:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(nazv_spec, 0, CHARINDEX('-', Group_number), 1) AS Spec, COUNT(*) AS COUNTGROUP
FROM     dbo.studenti_grupp
GROUP BY nazv_spec
```

что не так?

Comment: Ну, всё верно: необходимо 3 аргумента. Уберите лишний.

Comment: а какой лишний аргумент?